# SQL Calling A Saved Query from Another Query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, call

In other computing languages, you can call other methods or subroutines within a method or subroutine.

In VBA:

```
Public Sub x()
   Call y
End Sub
Private Sub y()
   Debug.Print "Hello World!"
End Sub
```

Can you do this in SQL?

```
Declare @FilePath as VarChar(Max)

Set @FilePath = '\\SomeServerExtension\MyFile.sql'

Execute @FilePath
```

It would save space and make the query appear cleaner.

Comment: You should read about and understand stored procedures. You nearly described the main benefit.

Answer (score 0):

You can [`EXEC`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms188332) other stored procedures from a stored procedure. You cannot execute arbitrary files (fortunately), even if the server could access them. It'd be a security nightmare, frankly.